# Is product (not the cartesian product) of two open balls in $\mathbb R$ an open ball?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Suppose that I have an open set $S\subset\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and we define $T=\{xy:(x,y)\in S^2\}$ 
The question is: is $T$ open in $\mathbb R$?

First I assert that T is open in $\mathbb R$.

To prove my assertion, I proceed by taking an arbitrary point $xy\in T$. Now, I want to find a radius  $\delta\gt 0$ such that $B(xy, \delta)\subset T$. 
Since $S$ is open in $\mathbb R$, it follows that there exists an $r\gt 0$ such that $B(x,r)\subset S\land B(y,r)\subset S$. 
I define the product $P:=B(x,r)B(y,r):=\{pq: (p,q)\in B(x,r)\times B(y,r)\}$ and clearly $P\subset T$. So my question here is: is $P$ an open ball (that is, an interval) in $\mathbb R$? If yes, then I am stuck at finding its centre and radius. If not, then if my assertion is true, there should exist some $r'\in (0,r)$ such that $B(xy, r')\subset P$ but I am having difficulty showing this also. (#)

I tried to take inspiration from an example: $S=(1,2)$. I claim that $T=(1,4)$ and my proof for this goes like this: 
It's clear that $T\subset (1,4)$. Now if $z\in (1,4)$ then clearly $\sqrt z\in S$ and we use the result $z=(\sqrt z)(\sqrt z)$ whence it follows that $z\in T$ (since $\sqrt z\in (1,2)$). Therefore, $(1,4)\subset T$ and we are done.

But I don't know how to do it in general case (#). Another way was to use the fact that every open set in $\mathbb R$ is a countable union of open intervals but that will make things very complicated.

Any hints/suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Is the symbol $G$ in the first sentence supposed to be $S$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Hi, yes you are right. I have fixed it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The title and the body ask two different questions. An [open ball](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OpenBall.html) is not the same as an open set.

Comment: @TonyK: I agree with you that not every open set is an open ball. But the post first gives a background where the question in title came from (background being S and T) and then describes the process followed to prove the assertion wherein open balls were encountered (I denoted it by $P$) but the answer below suggested that there was no need to consider the open balls and that the product of open balls is open set, which is what was required to proceed with my proof. :)

Comment: Err...wut?${}{}$

Comment: @TonyK: Never mind. I only wanted to say that question in the title and body are closely related.  :)

Comment: They are completely different questions! Why don't you just edit the title?

Comment: @TonyK: I asked about P in my question which is what my title says. Apart from that, I also ask a closely related question in post. I'm afraid I don't think a title edit is required. If you still feel otherwise, please change it as you like to make the title better. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First show that if $S \subset \Bbb R$ is open and $x \ne 0$ then $xS = \{ xy \mid y \in S \}$ is open. (This is true for subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ or arbitrary normed vector spaces.)

It follows that if $S_1, S_2\subset\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ are open then
$$
 S_1 S_2 =  \{ xy \mid (x, y) \in S_1 \times S_2 \} = \bigcup_{x \in S_1} xS_2
$$
is open as a union of open sets.

Actually this is true for all open subsets of $\Bbb R$, even if they contain zero: If either $S_1$ or $S_2$ does not contain zero then the above argument works. And if both sets contain zero then $S_1 S_2 = S_1'S_2$ where $S_1' = S_1 \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: Fantastic! Now, I understand the importance of $x\ne 0$, which is to give me a new $\delta$. I'll take any $xs\in xS$ and then I know there exists an $r\gt 0$ such that $(s-r,s+r)\subset S\implies (sx-|x|r, sx+|x|r)$ and this shows that $xS$ is open. What follows after that in your post makes perfect sense to me except may the part when $0$ is also contained(although I haven't yet thought  much on the case when $0$ is also contained in S). Many thanks :) +1

Comment: @Koro: You are welcome. I have added a sketch of the argument for sets containing zero.

Comment: Intuitively, it seems to me that if $0$ is contained in S, that will create problems. For example: Let $S$ be open. We write $S=L\cup \{0\}\cup R$, where $L=\{x\in S: x\lt 0\}$ and R is defined similarly. We consider $T$ as defined in post. We have $0\in T$ and we (intuitively) write $T=\{0\}\cup P$, where $P$ are non zero products (that is LR, $L^2$ etc.) and P is open because of the result just proved so $T$ is union of an open and a closed set, which is not necessarily open.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that before posting my last comment. I'll take a look. Thank you so much :)

Comment: In the very last sentence, are you referring to the sum of two open sets? The product of two vectors is not defined.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: You are right, that makes no sense. What I meant is the initial argument about multiplying an open set with a non-zero scalar.

Comment: I got that. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

In every topological group the product of an open set with an arbitrary set is open because multiplication with a fixed element defines a homeomorphism. So you have a union of open sets.